# jQuery Submenu still shows dropdown when folded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to fix my jQuery submenu. When I click on the burger button to collapsed all of my menu and the dropdown is still showing, it will actually look something like this:

How do I make it so the hamburger menu collapses appropriately?

Comment: Please don't edit your code out of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change icon click event function to something like this

```
$(".sidebar-icon").click(function() {                
    $(".content").toggleClass("sidebar-collapsed").toggleClass("sidebar-collapsed-back");
    $("#nav li ul").removeClass('disp');
    $("#nav li").find('span.fa').addClass('fa-plus').removeClass('fa-minus');
});
```

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shoaibakhter/oaxj6uab/5/